# Copy from template to rangelist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

```
function FunctionC12C31() {
  var allSheetTabs,i,L,thisSheet,thisSheetName,sheetsToExclude,value;
  sheetsToExclude = ['Template','Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  allSheetTabs = ss.getSheets();
  L = allSheetTabs.length;
  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
  thisSheet = allSheetTabs[i];
  thisSheetName = thisSheet.getName();
  //continue to loop if this sheet is one to exclude
  if (sheetsToExclude.indexOf(thisSheetName) !== -1) {continue;}
  value = thisSheet.getRangeList(['C12:C35','C5:C6','G16:G19','G4']).clearContent();
}}
```

Need help modifying this to instead of clearing contents
it will copy the formula from a RangeList(['C12:C35','C5:C6','G16:G19','G4'])
to be copied to from a Template Sheet too all sheet except to "sheetsToExclude" list.

or perhaps a different script?

1. copy from a template sheet RangeList(['C12:C35','C5:C6','G16:G19','G4'])
2. data will be formulas and need to be pasted on same RangeList
3. paste data to ALL sheets except from specified sheets. Like sheetsToExclude = ['Template','Sheet1','Sheet2'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the formulas from the cells `'C12:C35','C5:C6','G16:G19','G4'` of a template sheet. And, you want to put the retrieved formulas to the same ranges in the sheets except for `sheetsToExclude = ['Template','Sheet1','Sheet2']` in the active Spreadsheet.
- The template sheet is included in the same active Spreadsheet. The sheet name is "Template".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the values cannot be retrieved and put from the discrete cells using RangeList. So, in this case, it is required to use another method. In order to retrieve the formulas from the discrete cells and put the formulas to the discrete cells with the row process cost, I would like to propose using Sheets API. So, before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

In this script, "Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate" is used.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // These variables are from your showing script.
  var templateSheetName = "Template";
  var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName(templateSheetName);
  var sheetId = template.getSheetId();
  var gridRanges = ranges.map(r => {
    var range = template.getRange(r);
    var row = range.getRow();
    var col = range.getColumn();
    return {
      sheetId,
      startRowIndex: row - 1,
      endRowIndex: row - 1 + range.getNumRows(),
      startColumnIndex: col - 1,
      endColumnIndex: col - 1 + range.getNumColumns(),
    };
  });
  var requests = ss.getSheets().reduce((ar, s) => {
    if (!sheetsToExclude.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
      gridRanges.forEach(source => {
        var destination = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
        destination.sheetId = s.getSheetId();
        ar.push({ copyPaste: { source, destination, pasteType: "PASTE_FORMULA" } });
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the formulas are retrieved from `'C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'` of `templateSheetName` sheet, and the retrieved formulas are put into the same ranges in the sheets except for `sheetsToExclude`.

#### Modified script 2:

In this script, "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet" and "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate" are used.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // These variables are from your showing script.
  var templateSheetName = "Template";
  var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !sheetsToExclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  var formulas = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: ranges.map(r => `'${templateSheetName}'!${r}`), valueRenderOption: "FORMULA" }).valueRanges;
  var data = sheets.flatMap(s => formulas.slice().map(({ range, values }) => ({ range: range.replace(templateSheetName, s.getSheetName()), values })));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the formulas are retrieved from `'C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'` of `templateSheetName` sheet, and the retrieved formulas are put into the same ranges in the sheets except for `sheetsToExclude`.

#### Note:

- If you cannot use Sheets API, how about the following modified script? In this case, only the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      // These variables are from your showing script.
      var templateSheetName = "Template";
      var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
      var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'];

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var ssId = ss.getId();
      var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !sheetsToExclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));
      var formulas = ranges.map(r => ss.getSheetByName(templateSheetName).getRange(r).getFormulas());
      sheets.forEach(s => ranges.forEach((r, i) => s.getRange(r).setFormulas(formulas[i])));
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: solution verified. used last script and it worked perfectly. super thanks for this detailed instructions. middle script didn't work

Comment: @DCC Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: `var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];`


`var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'];`


can these be edited to get the info from a range from a specific sheet?

Comment: @DCC About your new question of `var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2']; var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4']; can these be edited to get the info from a range from a specific sheet?`, i would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do with your new question. I think that this is due to my very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill.

Comment: @DCC In order to correctly understand your new question, can you post it as new question? By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. At that time, If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: please check question: 74022181